# Is memory pinned when System.arrayCopy is called

Tags: java, java-native-interface, native

As far as I understand `System.arrayCopy` is implemented in native code.

However I was not able to find out anywhere whether the affected memory is pinned during processing of this method to prevent it from being moved by GC. Does Java pin it or how does it prevent moving onto obsolete address?

Comment: Which VM implementation are you referring to? HotSpot?

Comment: Are you asking if the JVM implementation “works properly”?

Comment: I was asking about the general concept, if there is some, not about a particular implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is pinned.  However, I expect that the code is safe from the effects of a GC moving the affected objects because the GC can only run when all threads have reached a GC safe-point.

---

I tried to check how this is implemented in the JVM source code (Java 11).  It is too complicated for me to get my head around.  The arraycopy method is intrinsic, and the actual code that does the copying is emitted by the optimizer.  However, I did see something which I think tells the runtime that an `arraycopy` call is not a safepoint.

On the other hand I saw nothing that suggests any form of memory pinning.

Comment: Is this behaviour specific to System.arrayCopy or it is expected for any native method, i.e. GC can not occur (that GC safe point can not be reached) while some native method is being processed?

Comment: This is specific to arrayCopy.